# Hibernate Query cache understanding

Tags: hibernate, caching

I have gont through lot of materials but I am not able to clear one doubt for hibernate second level cache.

1) Lets say, I have a query which returns 1000 records. (for eg, from employee where age>30).
I have made the query as cacheable. In the meantime the number of records have increased and now the results should be 2000 for the same query.Now next time when I execute the same query, how hibernate fetches the records from cache. Does it fetches only the new records?

2) Scenario 2. Lets say I execute the query(for eg, from employee where age>30). I got records of 1000. Now the records are updated internally. Again I execute the same query. In this case how hibernate fetches?

Answer (score 2):

> Query cache does not cache the state of the actual entities in the
>   result set; it caches only identifier values and results of value
>   type.

**Scenario 1:** Hibernate stores timestamps along with query to track new records and if hibernate found a new record then will fire query again evicting old data.

**Scenario 2:** This  will always return you updated record becasue actual state object was never cached with query

for more detail refer to [link](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)